# php encoding issue, &nbsp; being replaced by Â

Tags: php, html

```
$str="Asia&nbsp;Holiday house";
```

I will remove only `&nbsp;` and also I open in this text in .csv file and It will print i.e. `AsiaÂ Holiday house`
I only remove `Â` this character.
I want this text in this form `Asia Holiday house`

Comment: This sounds like an encoding error. You might try changing your file encoding to UTF-8 if it isn't already...

Comment: &nbsp; is a url encoded space http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: The other place you can declare the encoding is in the <head> section of the html document, e.g. <meta charset="UTF-8">

Answer (score 2):

Use following line if you just want to replace all `&nbsp;`:

```
$str = str_replace("&nbsp;"," ",$str);
```

OR add following line before any output on your page for an encoding issue:

```
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Following link might be very useful link to solve your problem :

http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,2671